# Doctrine repository findOneBy print sql. why? how can I disable this?

Tags: codeigniter, orm, doctrine

```
$rep = $em->getRepository('Entities\User');
$user = $rep->findOneBy(array('email'=>'d*****e@s*****o.com'));
```

print output:

> SELECT t0.uid AS uid1, t0.email AS email2, t0.password AS password3, t0.name AS name4, t0.surname AS surname5, t0.matrikel AS matrikel6, t0.status AS status7, t0.registration_time AS registration_time8, t0.gid AS gid9 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.email = ? LIMIT 1 array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "d*****e@s*****o.com" } array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "string" }

I just wanna the entity, not print output. Where can I disable this?

Comment: is it your real email address? Is not a good idea to publish question with sensitive data...

Comment: yes, not a good idea, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the [Echo SQL Logger enabled](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#configuration-options). Turn it off.